# full width banner from within a container

Tags: css

The layout of my page has a wrapper div with the following css:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 980px;
min-height: 100%;
```

Is there a way to have a div within this div span the entire screen? The only way I know is to give the div an absolute position but I am not sure if that is a good idea. I read something recently to avoid using "magic numbers" within the css which I would need to do here in order for the banner to be located a certain distance from the top of the page i.e. top: 233px;

What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: You can't make something be wider than its parent without "magic numbers". Anything stopping you moving the div out of its parent?

Comment: Well the parent is basically the body of the page. Making the position absolute, and then top: 1 seems to move the div to exactly where I want it, but top: 0 is at the top of the page. So for some reason any number in the top seems to move it about 200px... Not sure why yet and I can't really post the code yet so I will keep digging.

Comment: I avoid any attempt at what you're trying to do in my code. The only way I would accomplish what you're trying to do is with javascript, but usually if I have a div, what is inside the div will be strictly contained inside that div.

Answer (score 1):

Better to have the banner out of the wrapper div. A block bigger than its parent is not "natural".
There's a trick though, using this:

```
position:absolute;
left:0;
right:0;
```

Note: this won't work when parent is position:relative.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, `width: inherit;` would make the child div the same size as the parent.

Comment: Trying to not inherit the width of the parent I think. The width of the parent is 980px but I want to span 100%